# How to get Resultset from MySQL if no of columns changes

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I have a Table like below

```
CREATE TABLE Statistics(Stat_Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        Period  VARCHAR(55),
                        Location VARCHAR(255),
                        Rate_per_SqFt INT)

INSERT INTO Statistics(Period, Location, Rate_per_SqFt)
                VALUES('June', 'Location A', 2500),
                      ('June', 'Location B', 2740),
                      ('June', 'Location C', 3200),
                      ('July', 'Location A', 2650),
                      ('July', 'Location B', 2800),
                      ('July', 'Location C', 3250),
                      ('August', 'Location A', 2750),
                      ('August', 'Location B', 2950),
                      ('August', 'Location C', 3230),
                      ('October', 'Location A', 2950),
                      ('October', 'Location B', 3950),
                      ('October', 'Location C', 3530);
```

I Used the below proc

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test.stats_report;
CREATE PROCEDURE test.`stats_report`()
BEGIN
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN Location = ''',
      Location,
      ''' then Rate_per_SqFt ELSE 0 end) AS ',
      CONCAT('`',Location,'`')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM statistics;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Period, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM Statistics 
                   GROUP BY Period');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

It brings output as below

```
 Period   Location A     Location B     Location C 
 June        2500          2740           3200
 July        2650          2800           3250
 August      2750          2950           3230
 October     2950          3950           3530
```

Since I dynamically generate columns in MySQL Procedure I dont know how to get the rows from the result set in PHP by using MySQLi Bind Method or any thing else.

How to get the rows from Result set  in which the number of columns is not know.

Please note I want Location A, Location B and Location C which i specified as Column in Result set.

Now when I add New Location D its going to come as new column.

You can have look at the MySQL Table [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdf9c/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can always work with the rows from a result set as an array and use foreach to loop through them. You didn't include your PHP code so we don't know whether this is via `PDO` or `MySQLi`.. so this may be a bit off the mark.. *but*..

Information about the resultset is available from the [metadata](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php) . For `MySQLi` start with:

```
/* get resultset for metadata */   
$result = $stmt->result_metadata();
```

Then use this to call `fetch_fields` as [such](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php):

```
/* Get field information for all columns */
$fields = $result->fetch_fields();

foreach ($fields as $field) {}
```

[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) has similar functions.